# Can we apply here the Cayley–Hamilton theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, characteristic-polynomial, cayley-hamilton

We have the matrix \begin{equation*}A:=\begin{pmatrix}3 & 1 & 0 & -1& -1 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 1\end{pmatrix}\in M_5(\mathbb{R})\end{equation*}

The characteric polynomial is \begin{equation*}P_A(\lambda)=(2-\lambda)^5\end{equation*}

The eigenvalue $\lambda=2$ has the algebraic multiplicity $5$.

The eigenspace is \begin{equation*}\left \{\begin{pmatrix}e\\ 0\\ c\\ 0\\  e\end{pmatrix}:  c, e\in \mathbb{R}\right \}=\left \{e\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0\\  1\end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\\ 0\\  0\end{pmatrix}:  c, e\in \mathbb{R}\right \}\end{equation*}

So the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda=2$ is $2$.

How can we calculate $(A − 2I_5)^3$ ?

Can we apply here the Cayley–Hamilton theorem?

Comment: What is $u_5$? Is it one of the standard basis vector in $M_5(\Bbb{R})$?

Comment: Oh I meant the unit matrix, I corrected it. It should be $(A − 2I_5)^3$  @AnuragA

Comment: The Cayley-Hamilton theorem tells you that $(A-2I)^5=0$; it's not difficult to show a matrix $B$ having the single eigenvalue $2$ with algebraic multiplicity $5$ and geometric multiplicity $2$, but $B^3\ne0$. In the given case, it does happen that $(A-2I)^3=0$, but not because of CH.

Comment: Why does this hold? I got stuck right now. @egreg

Comment: @MaryStar “This” what? The fact that $(A-2I)^3=0$? Because it does *for this particular matrix*. You cannot in general deduce that $(B-2I)^3=0$ from the information that the eigenvalue is unique and the eigenspace has dimension $2$.

Comment: @egreg we can deduce this kind of case by using minimal polynomial! And there can be infinitely many case of this kind, and you can create them also, for example any n×n diagonalizable matrix have only one eigenvalue a with A.M. n then clearly it is shown that (A-aI)=0 while characteristics polynomial is (A-aI)ⁿ=0.

Comment: @Subhajit Yes, of course, but computing the minimal polynomial cannot be done with CH. For the given matrix the minimal polynomial is indeed $(x-2)^3$, but you cannot deduce it just from the eigenspace.

Comment: And also it can be (x-2)⁴!

Comment: Why not? Using Jordon canonical form, it can be done,

Comment: Also along with the G.M. of eigenvalue together with AM.

Comment: And you can see it what I have done! Not only for this matrix, take any arbitrary one , and use this rule, then what will happen you can see it by yourself?

Comment: @egreg is this rule still having doubt! Please tell me , if you get something different.

Answer (score 1):

Here, dimension of eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue 2 is 2, There are two Jordan canonical forms  possible! So, in one Jordan canonical form, there can be two blocks possible which are of order 3 and order 2 and in another of Jordon canonical form, there can also be possiblity for two blocks of order 4 and 1,
But through the first case max order of block is 3, hence there be possiblity of minimal polynomial of order 3, hence we can use Cayley Hamilton's theorem!                                        For the first case ,Jordon canonical form, $$
    \begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$